# NodeJS + Web3 + Infura Ropsten - Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: web3js, nodejs, ropsten, infura

I have problem with invalid response to ethereum from BE NodeJS app.
I got error like:

Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Below I'd attached my simple code for testing connection.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl));
const contract_web3 = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

console.log("Config Data: \n", providerUrl, "\n", config.privateKey, "\n", contractAddress);

contract_web3.methods.getDocuments().call((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle error here
        console.log("Test call error: ", err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Test call: ", result);
    }
})
```

I'v readed about HDWalletProvider, but I havent dive in it yet.

Regards!

Comment: What is the value of `providerUrl`, and do you have an Ethereum Node listening at this port/socket/connection?

Comment: Hello again, value of providerUrl is https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/my_project_id/. Yes I have deployed smartcontract via remix ide to ropsten with my MetaMask account.

Comment: What is the value of `contractAddress`, and have you verified the contract at that address on etherscan (so that we can view its source code)?

Comment: Yes I had transaction on etherscan, with contract creation https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x55d9020da2b287954427b68840a8b846d240e42b

Answer (score 2):

Ok. With this code the parts were errors might occur are very limited.

Make sure `providerUrl` has the correct value.

I hope you filled `contractAddress` correctly.

`Abi` is the bigger problem. Do a `console.log` of it. I would suggest a `JSON.parse` on the abi. This might fix the problem.

**EDIT:** What is your web3 version? Make sure not to use an outdated one.

Comment: Using an incorrect ABI could not possibly result in an `Invalid JSON RPC response` error.

Comment: Proxy could be a problem? I have proxy cert for npm, but maybe that nodeJS is prevented from making action by company proxy from app level. I will try behind proxy.

Comment: Without proxy it is working, but it seems to be connectet wrong.How can I connect ropsten contract deployed with remix ide + metamask? in code I have provateKey from metamask, contract address is correct, from etherscan copied. I have created project on infura but I thought it is something like gateway to ropsten.